# how i can window over the gridpanel?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

When I reload my grid 
`Ext.StoreMgr.lookup('store').reload();`
then I want to remove loading icon and loading background because `Ext.wndow` open then loading background overlap on the window.
So Please tell me how i will remove it?

Answer (score 2):

The grid view has a `loadMask` config you can set.

```
Ext.create("Ext.grid.Panel", {
    // some config options here...
    viewConfig: {
        // Setting this false should disable the automatic load masking
        loadMask: false
    }
});
```